# How this site do this with Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I came to this site by chance. I see it uses Google Maps, but what they did to the map will be displayed in such a way? (No icons course)

http://abbyputinski.com/#/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom map tiles are achieved via [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling). [Check out the API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StyledMapType) to see what can be customized and to what level.

Answer (score 2):

as per @Andre said, it is styled.

If you want to play around with the style , you can try it here : [FlatUIMaps](http://flatuimaps.com/).
You can download the configuration in json format after changing the layer.